# Error: No module named django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have an old CentOS machine, where a software app written for Django 1.4.x is running. The software requires Python2.7. So I upgraded the implementation to Python2.7 and installed the various necessary software.

on the python2.7 command prompt

```
>>> import django
```

Works perfectly. I am able to play around with everything fine. Even when I `print sys.path` it shows directories fine.

But running

```
python2.7 manage.py runserver
```

or any other command throws up an error

```
python2.7 manage.py runserver
Error: No module named django
```

This is the first time I have seen such an issue in last 10 years. The software works perfectly in the ubuntu version which has python2.7 installed.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? If so, have you activated your environment first?

Comment: No.Virtualenv. There is no other app running. App runs as root

Comment: Does django show up under `python2.7 pip list`? What version does it say?

Comment: How have you installed Django? How do you run the python2.7 command prompt, and in which directory? In which directory do you run `python2.7 manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Check pip freeze and see if django is installed

Comment: Answer is Yes. Django is showing up. The app has been pulled in from bitbucket account. Django has been installed using pip, and all dependencies are showing on command prompt with the import command

Comment: python manage.py runs, showing the help options. But python manage.py commands don't

Comment: Is there any local file `django.py` (or possibly a `django` directory) lying around?

Comment: Can you add the code from `manage.py` to your question (I don't assume it's different than usual, but better check)?

Comment: @Evert. No there are no local django file.

Comment: do a 'which pip'. Make sure, that django was installed using the same pip. When you would have installed Python2.7 manually, you should have also installed the corresponding pip version. Make sure that the python2.7 path is set